# Display application name in Session Information when connecting via JDBC

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, pgadmin

I create a connection to a postgres 9 database using the stardard JDBC driver.

```
...
Connection myCon = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test?&user=test&password=test"); 
...
```

When I check the server status with PgAdmin and display all database sessions, I can see that the "Application Name" is not set for my Session. Is there a way to set the application name in the JDBC connection?

Comment: Time to answer my own question, it can be SET with the following code: 

stmt = Con.prepareStatement("SET application_name = 'myApp'");
stmt.execute();

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That is possible to set application name as connection parameter since Postgres [JDBC 9.1dev-900](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/changelog.html#version_9.1dev-900):

> Add support for setting application_name on both connection startup
>   and later through Connection.setClientInfo. (jurka)

ex: `jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/DbName?ApplicationName=MyApp`

or `Connection.setClientInfo("ApplicationName", "My App")`

For previous versions you could do this by setting `application_name` runtime parameter:

```
s.execute("SET application_name TO 'MyApp'");
```

Comment: Just in case it would be helpful for someone : this can be done specifically for Oracle databases with an additionnal property : ((BasicDataSource) datasource).addConnectionProperty("v$session.program", "Explicit connection label"). This will then be showed in the v$session Oracle view. Of course this ways works only for Oracle and your JDBC solution - whom i was unaware of - should be more robust.