# How to set application name in a Postgresql JDBC url?

Tags: postgresql, url, jdbc, postgresql-9.2

I want to set the application name of the connections of my application. So when I list the rows in `pg_stat_activity` I can have a non empty `application_name` column.

I have setup the following JDBC url for connecting to my Postgresql database:

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5435/MyDB?application-name=MyApp
```

I have tried also this url with no more success.

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5435/MyDB?application_name=MyApp
```

What is the correct parameter name ?

Here is my JDBC driver version:  **9.1-901.jdbc4**

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7145908/display-application-name-in-session-information-when-connecting-via-jdbc

Comment: have you tried to pass the application_name with properties?!

Comment: @user2511414 I have already checked the question you suggest. properties is not an option.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Looking at the [PostgreSQL JDBC 9.1 documentation, connection parameters](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/91/connect.html#connection-parameters), the correct property name in the JDBC url is `ApplicationName`:

> `ApplicationName = String`
>
> Specifies the name of the application that is using the connection. This allows a database administrator to see what applications are connected to the server and what resources they are using through views like `pg_stat_activity`

So try:

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5435/MyDB?ApplicationName=MyApp
```

Be aware some comments suggest that this is broken in the 9.1 version driver. Given it is a more than 5 year old version, you should upgrade to a newer version anyway. Check https://jdbc.postgresql.org/ for the latest version and use that.

Comment: I tried this parameter (`ApplicationName` or `ApplicationName`) with no much success :(

Comment: In that case, I'd suggest to file a bug with postgresql

Comment: This works for me with this version of the PG driver: **9.2-1003-jdbc4**.

Comment: Works for me with driver version 9.4.1212

Comment: Must be broken for 9.1, see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/39099066/32453

Comment: @rogerdpack I added a note to that effect, however given the 9.1 driver is almost 7 years old, you should be using a newer version than that anyway. The driver version is not tied to a specific PostgreSQL version, which is also why they now changed the version scheme to 42.x.